# Get the text associated with a href element in a given page in scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

Currently my 'yield' in my scrapy spider looks as follows :

```
yield {
        'hreflink':mylink,
        'Parentlink':response.url
            }
```

This returns me a dict

```
 {
    'hreflink':"https://www.southeasthealth.org/wp-content/uploads/Southeast-Health-Standard-Charges-2022.xlsx",
    'Parentlink': "https://www.southeasthealth.org/financial-information-price-transparency/"
    }
```

Now, I also want the 'text' that is associated with this particular hreflink, in that particular Parentlink. So my final output should look like

```
 {
    'hreflink':"https://www.southeasthealth.org/wp-content/uploads/Southeast-Health-Standard-Charges-2022.xlsx",
    'Parentlink': "https://www.southeasthealth.org/financial-information-price-transparency/",
     'Yourtext' : "Download Pricing Info"
    }
```

What would be the simplest way to achieve that. I want to use Xpath expressions to get the "text" in a parentlink where href element = @href .

So far Here is what I tied -
Yourtext  = response.xpath('//a[@href='+json.dumps(each)+']//text()').get()
but its not printing anything. I tried printing my response and it returns the right page - 'https://www.southeasthealth.org/financial-information-price-transparency/'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to get the text belonging to the link `Download Pricing Info`.

I suggest you try using:

```
response.xpath("//span[@class='fusion-button-text']//text()").get()
```

Comment: Check on your placement of the square brackets. Seems incorrect

Comment: @msenior_ thanks for picking that up! late night ...

Comment: Hello , I cannot use @classs because every website will be different  (I need to scrape multiple pages). I can only use href. and I did try response.xpath('//a[@href='+json.dumps(each)+']//text()').get() but its not printing anything. I tried printing my response and it returns the right page - 'https://www.southeasthealth.org/financial-information-price-transparency/' so I am not sure why my reponse.xpath is not printing anything

Comment: @user3234112 can you upload the script that you're working with?

Comment: Yes, Its too long to paste it here, so I appended the question and added it in the end. So if you run that spider , it shows under 'my_text' :None. I was expecting to see 'my_text' : 'Download Pricing Info' .

Comment: @user3234112 If you know that the text will always be the same, you can try: ```//span[contains(text(),'Download Pricing Info')]```

Comment: It's not same unfortunately but that's a great suggestion.Thats why I need to search for that respective text using that specific href.

Comment: Sorry, you have slightly confused me. I thought you needed `Download Pricing Info` as shown in your post. However, after looking at the `.xlsx` sheet, I could not find anything matching this. Although, it seems you have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question.

```
'//a[@href='+json.dumps(each)+']//text()'
```

This is the correct expression however the href link 'each' is case sensitive and it needs to match exactly for this Xpath to work.